# To simulate click on first node in react

Tags: reactjs

I am writing unit test cases. Following is a part of the code

```
const container = mount( <Container  />, withReduxContext(store));
container.find('.task').simulate('click');
```

But I am getting two nodes with the classname task. How to simulate click on just the first node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [first()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/first.html#first--reactwrapper)

```
const container = mount( <Container  />, withReduxContext(store));
container.find('.task').first().simulate('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in [first()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/first.html) function in Enzyme.

```js
const container = mount( <Container  />, withReduxContext(store));
container.find('.task').first().simulate('click');
```